# GridView SelectedIndexChanged not firing

Tags: .net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I've read all the posts, and tried everything.
Now begging for your insight.

I create a GridView

```
GridView aGridView = new GridView();
```

and give it this ID

```
aGridView.ID = "theGridView";
```

assign the SelectIndexChanged event handler

```
aGridView.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(aGridView_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

and then add it to aPanel.Controls on my page.

Everything appears as expected.

I add this to each row when row data is bound

```
e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = "this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((GridView)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

and have this handler waiting with a debug break point

```
void aGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

but it never gets called.

The generated link attached to the "onclick" of the row looks like this

```
javascript:__doPostBack('theGridView','Select$0')
```

When I look at the page source, the GridView ID is indeed "theGridView".

Ideas?
I've tried setting EnableEventValidation="false" in the page .aspx with no success.

Comment: when do you add it to the Panel? which event?

Comment: How do you select the row? Do you have a column with select button? A grid view should have a postback inside it so as to fire this event. I am talking about `<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />`